# intellij dependency tree programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'd like to create some code analysis. In my project I'm calling external services with `callExternalService(Service service, Object request)`. I want to get all callers of this method and track it to all methods which are annotated with spring's `RequestMapping` annotation. Basically create some mapping of ES -> RestControllers.
I know that in IntelliJ I can create call hierarchy tree but I'd like to crate this programmatically to have that mapping every time when someone want's it from me (in case I forget to create documentation).

Can somebody point me to some code or documentation how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, you'll need to create a plugin. see https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics.html for details.
- Then,

  - find all usages of the selected method (you can use com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ReferencesSearch for that),
  - organize them in a tree and
  - show to a user.

To show the tree, you can either use a good old JTree, or plug into IDEA hierarchy browser subsystem. 
To do the latter, implement com.intellij.ide.hierarchy.HierarchyProvider, register it in your plugin.xml and you will get your own hierarchy browser in the new tool window. 
See com.intellij.ide.hierarchy.call.JavaCallHierarchyProvider for the example how to do that.

Comment: is there way how to use this without creating plugin? E.g. library which will get maven project and process it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid the only way "to crate this programatically" as you requested is to write a plugin. Theoretically there maybe a plugin which supports some sort of DSL for writing highly customizable non-standard searches like yours. But you would need to write that plugin first. k)

Comment: If I'd like to work with simillar functionality like in call hierarchy, can you point me to some source code where can I see it? I mean I'd like to see sources of action behind `Ctrl + alt + h` shortcut. I want to add something simillar (currently without gui). So click at method and highlight it -> right click or action shortcut -> do custom processing.

Comment: When user invokes Navigate|Call hierarchy, the com.intellij.ide.hierarchy.actions.BrowseCallHierarchyAction.actionPerformed() is called which (for java method) calls com.intellij.ide.hierarchy.call.JavaCallHierarchyProvider.createHierarchyBrowser() which creates com.intellij.ide.hierarchy.call.CallHierarchyBrowser component and shows it to the user. All sources are available in https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community